# $_GET method inside a while loop

Tags: php, forms, get

Hi I am trying create a system for making my own invoices, and printing them, so I created inputs with a while loop, depending on the number of articles I have entered, using the code below

```
<?php
$cont=1;
$numero = $_REQUEST['numeroa'];

while($cont<=$numero) {

  echo $cont;
  echo "       <input class='Descripcion$cont' placeholder='Descripcion :' />";
  echo "       <input class='Precio' name='precio$cont' placeholder='Precio :' onkeyup='AddInputs()' /><br>";

  $cont++;
  } 
  echo "<textarea name='comment' >Escriba sus comentarios....</textarea>"; 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['cont']=$cont;
   ?>
```

This **sends post info to another php page**, so I get something like this on the url

```
http://localhost/pruebas/facturapdf.php?precio1=1&precio2=2&precio3=3&precio4=4&precio5=5
```

I tried to get the variables using this code but I had no success

```
session_start();
$contp=$_SESSION['cont'];
while($cont<=$contp) {

  $articulos[$cont]=$_GET['precio$cont'];
  echo $articulos[$cont];
  $cont++;
}
```

Is there a way I can use the get method changing the number each loop??

If there isn't, how can I get all the variables, knowing they are different every time, depending on the user input

thanks in advance..

Comment: String interpolation works in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: `$_GET['precio'.$cont]` given that the $cont is a var this will loop the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you're using single quotes for when you should be using double..

```
$articulos[$cont] = $_GET["precio$cont"];
```

Further, you could actually pass in an array directly as query data rather than appending a count value and looping through them.

```
echo "       <input class='Descripcion' placeholder='Descripcion :' />";
echo "       <input class='Precio' name='precio[]' placeholder='Precio :' onkeyup='AddInputs()' /><br>";
```

Note that I've simply changed `name='precio$cont'` to `name='precio[]'`

you can then access this as an array when submitted

```
$precioArr = $_GET['precio'];
```

Just to demostrate

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($precioArr); $i++) {
    echo $precioArr[$i];
}
```

So you could actually use this for the requirements that you mentioned

> If there isn't, how can I get all the variables, knowing they are different every time, depending on the user input

This can be demonstrated using this code

```
<?php

    echo "query data:<br>";
    print_r($_GET['array']);

    echo "<br>";

    echo "query keys:<br>";
    print_r(array_keys($_GET['array']));

?>
```

So if you had a form like so:

```
<form action="demo.php" method="GET">
    <input name="array[2]" type="text" value="11">
    <input name="array[4]" type="text" value="11">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This would pass a query query of `?array[2]=11&array[4]=11`, the result you'd get is:

```
query data:
Array ( [2] => 11 [4] => 11 ) 
query keys:
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$contp=$_SESSION['cont'];
while($cont<=$contp) {

  $articulos[$cont]=$_GET['precio'. $cont];
  echo $articulos[$cont];
  $cont++;
}
```

difference to the original: `'precio'. $cont`
this will concat the value of the variable `$cont` to the string literal `'precio'`.

what you wrote (`'precio$cont'`) will always  be the literal string it is. no variable used.

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?